# Lint warning: Pointer member not directly freed or zeroed by destructor

Tags: data-structures, compiler-warnings, lint

I have an operation DeleteCurrentNode(...) which works on a doubly linked list (DLL). The purpose of this operation is to delete a node which is pointed my DLL cursor/index. 
(I have a cursor/index on the list pointing to the node that was recently used)

I have written code for the destructor which calls the DeleteCurrentNode(...) until the list is empty.
During compilation, the following lint warning is raised.
Warnings:Pointer member not directly freed or zeroed by destructor.

How to get solve this warning ?

Thanks for any help !!

Comment: Add source code and add tag of the relevant language

Comment: Also, which lint tool is used?